# Displaying current section in slide headline

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer

I would like to display the current section name in the headline of a presentation (i.e., similar to a stripped-down `infolines` outer theme). The following MWE *almost* does what I want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % temporarily redefine headline to be empty
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
}}

\setbeamercolor{mysection}{fg=bg,bg=fg}

\title{The Title}
\author{A.~U.~Thor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle % We don't want a headline
\begin{frame}{Slide 0}Zero\end{frame} % Still don't want a headline

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\leavevmode%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{mysection}%
        \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hspace{.5em}\insertsectionhead\hfil}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip0pt}

\section{Section A}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}One\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Slide 2}Two\end{frame}

\section{Section B}
\begin{frame}{Slide 3}Three\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In particular the above document has the following *desired* properties:

- Does not display a headline until after sections have started
- Does not display a headline on the interstitial slides that announce the start of a new section

It has two problems:

1. It avoids showing a headline in the first few slides by simply setting the template (`\setbeamertemplate{headline}...`) in the middle of the document. I would like to do this sort of definition in the preamble (so that I can refactor it into a real outer theme in its own file).
2. It generates overfull vboxes (`Overfull \vbox (9.66663pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []`).

How can I fix these problems? For example, perhaps problem (1) be solved by introducing some conditional logic to detect whether the section number is zero.

Comment: Maybe switch the empty and the customized `headline` templates? That is, write your `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\leavevmode ...}` in the preamble, but uses `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` for the first few frames (surround them in a pair of `{}`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

1. Move your customized `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\leavevmode ...}` into the preamble.
2. Create a new environment `nobeamerheadline` that issues `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}` at its beginning.

Bonus feature of the above solution: It allows you to suppress headline in other places too, for instance, the Thank you/Question? frame(s). Here is my approach:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}% temporarily redefine headline to be empty
  \frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
  \endgroup
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\leavevmode
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{mysection}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hspace{.5em}\insertsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vskip0pt}

\setbeamercolor{mysection}{fg=bg,bg=fg}

\newenvironment{nobeamerheadline}{%
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
}{%
  \endgroup
}

\title{The Title}
\author{A.~U.~Thor}

\begin{document}

\begin{nobeamerheadline}
\maketitle % We don't want a headline
\begin{frame}{Slide 0}Zero\end{frame} % Still don't want a headline
\end{nobeamerheadline}

\section{Section A}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}One\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Slide 2}Two\end{frame}

\section{Section B}
\begin{frame}{Slide 3}Three\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

BTW, I did not get any `Overfull \vbox` warning messages.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. The only problem is that it hinders factoring out the code into an *outer theme* since the main document must remember to use `\begin{nobeamerheadline}...\end{nobeamerheadline}`.

Comment: I think the reason your solution does not generate overfull boxes is because the template is in place (with no conditionals) at the start of the document, which is when the headline is test-typeset in order to measure its height. See the answer and comments of @samcarter to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to technically display the headline on all frames, but make it invisible before sections start:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{{
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{} 
    \frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
}}

\title{The Title}
\author{A.~U.~Thor}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \ifnum\thesection>0
        \setbeamercolor{mysection}{bg=fg}
    \else
        \setbeamercolor{mysection}{bg=bg}
    \fi
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{mysection}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hspace{.5em}\insertsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle % We don't want a headline
\begin{frame}{Slide 0}Zero\end{frame} % Still don't want a headline

\section{Section A}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}One\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Slide 2}Two\end{frame}

\section{Section B}
\begin{frame}{Slide 3}Three\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Ultimately I think it would be easiest to just use plain frames where appropriate:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\title{The Title}
\author{A.~U.~Thor}
\setbeamercolor{mysection}{bg=fg,fg=bg}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{mysection}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hspace{.5em}\insertsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \frametitle{Slide 0}
    Zero
\end{frame}

\section{Section A}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}One\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Slide 2}Two\end{frame}

\section{Section B}
\begin{frame}{Slide 3}Three\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I notice that setting `\headheight` can't be done in the preamble (it seems that it must happen after `\begin{document}`). In fact, I tried adding to `\AtBeginDocument` and that also does not work. Is there any way to move that out of the main body of the document?

Comment: I suppose one way to move it out of the main body is to always typeset a headline but make it blank when it's not really needed.

Comment: @banbh As I said, it is automatically calculated at the begin of the document, so it must be corrected afterwards.

Comment: @banbh An easy hack could be to make it white if section number <0

Comment: @banbh Or to display it on all slides and use a `plain` frame for the frames you don't want the headline.

Comment: I think I agree with your second two solutions (which avoid modifying `\headheight`). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447541/.

Comment: @banbh Yes, the idea to mess with the headheight probably was one of my not so brilliant ideas. I removed it from my answer.