# Changing \headheight pushes footline off slide

Tags: beamer, header-footer

How do I prevent the footline from being pushed off the slide if I change a Beamer document's `\headheight`?

Suppose, in a Beamer document, you want to change the size of the headline by altering `\headheight`. (One reason you might want to do this is if your headline template is empty at the start of the document; see, for example, [Displaying current section in slide headline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447384/displaying-current-section-in-slide-headline) and the answer of @samcarter). If you do this then you may push the footline off the slide. For example, here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer} % version 3.50

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{FOOTLINE}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}One\end{frame}
\setlength{\headheight}{.5ex}
\begin{frame}{Slide 2}Two\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The footline is displayed correctly on Slide 1, but on Slide 2 it is partially pushed off the slide.

Perhaps I should not be altering `\headheight` mid-document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [Displaying current section in slide headline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447384/displaying-current-section-in-slide-headline#comment1124301_447392) messing with the `\headheight` was one of my not so great ideas (that's why I deleted it). The problem with the footline can be repaired, but I'm not sure what other problems this might cause...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{FOOTLINE}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}One\end{frame}
\setlength{\headheight}{.5ex}

\makeatletter
    \advance\textheight by-\headheight%
  \@colht\textheight%
  \@colroom\textheight%
  \vsize\textheight%
\makeatother


\begin{frame}{Slide 2}Two\end{frame}
\end{document}
```